# Is it possible to publish project on npm and install from specific directory

Tags: angular, npm, gitlab

I am building a library for Angular. I wonder if it is possible to publish the whole library together with a ready-made angular application on gitlab or npm, but when a user wants to install a library, the npm will install  only source files - let's say from the /dist directory, without copying files that are unnecessary (the whole application).

I would like to avoid a situation where I have two repositories, one with a test application (used only by me), and the other with the source code available to clients.

Does anyone know answer for my question?

Best Regards,

Bloodcast69

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [files field](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) of `package.json`, which is a whitelist of files that are going to be published to the registry.

For instance, if you want only the `dist/` folder, then you can add this field to `package.json`:

```
"files": ["dist"],
```

You can also create a `.npmignore` file, where you can exclude files from being published to the registry. It has similar syntax to `.gitignore`. So you can ignore the src folder with this `.npmignore` file:

```
src
```